# How can I disable ext4 has_journal option on dedicated server?

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, tune2fs

I have Ubuntu 10.04 dedicated server with SSD drive. Hence I want to disable the file system journal.

Normally this can be done like this "tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/md2". However the root file system is in read-write mode so tune2fs prints an error. The "-f" does not work.

Maybe during boot there is some script which is executed having root file system mounted read-only. So I can add above command to that script.

BTW I can reinstall OS but ext2 isn't available. A server provider admin web page doesn't allow to pass create partition options when reinstalling OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to remount the root partition read-only if you can afford to turn off enough services for a few minutes. Use `lsof +f -- /` to find out what programs have files open for writing. In particular, if `/var/log` is on the root partition, you'll have to turn off logging; and `/tmp` had better be on tmpfs or a separate filesystem.

If your hosting provider gives you console access, you can pass `init=/bin/sh` on the kernel command line (this runs a shell instead of `init`) and run `tune2fs` from there.